# How to pass a screen (not the initial one of that stack) to another stack

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am currently developing a react-native application. This application has a bottom tab navigaton and a top tab navigation. Both are defined in the router as different stacks.

```
Stack A:
    Screen A.1
    Screen A.2
    Screen A.3
    Screen A.4

Stack B:
    Screen B.1
    Screen B.2
    Screen B.3
    Screen B.4
```

Screen B.1 is calling Stack A and should show Screen A.1, which it does.

Screen B.4 should call Screen A.2 of Stack A and I have no clue how to solve that problem. I tried to do it with

```
navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index].routeName;
```

but it did not work.
Can anyone help me?

Thank you! 
A